# Can't decide MySQL or MongoDB for the Project

Tags: mysql, mongodb, transactions

I have problem with selecting database MongoDB or MySQL for my project.This is the MongoDB database design.

```
Ride:{
    Id: 12wtywbty21,
    driverId: t1@gmail.com,
    slectedRouteJunctions:[
                            Loc:{
                                    lat:50.25,
                                    lng:67.56
                            },
                            Loc:{
                                    lat:50.25,
                                    lng:67.56
                            },
                            Loc:{
                                    lat:50.25,
                                    lng:67.56
                            }
    ],
    availableSeats: 5 ,
    startDateTime: 2015-04-05 7:00 ,
    passengers:[
                Passanger:{
                    passangerId:t3gmail.com,
                    joinTime:2015-04-05 7:15,
                    endTime:null
                },
                Passanger:{
                    passangerId:t4gmail.com,
                    joinTime:2015-04-05 7:15,
                    endTime:null
                }
    ]
}

-----------------------------------------------------

User:{
    userId:t4gmail.com,
    name:t4,
    currentLocation:{
        lat:50,
        lng:60
    },
    friendRequest:[
                    FriendRequest:{ 
                        f_request_id:2,
                        friend_type:1
                    },
                    FriendRequest{  
                        f_request_id:3,
                        friend_type:2
                    }

    ]
}

--------------------------------------------------------

FriendRequest{
    id:1,
    RequestDate:2015-04-05 7:15 ,
    assecptData:2015-04-05 7:15 ,
    State : 0

}
```

I want to store these kind of data set.But the problem is MongoDB does't support for relational query.When retrieving data ,MongoDB works with only one Collection.So I have retrieve data step by step .I think it will increase traffic between an application and the database server .

Another problem is MongoDB does't support Transactions. Is it a problem for a good application. I don't have good knowledge about Transactions. Because of  these reasons I also think about MySQL instead of MongoDB. But I can't clearly decide what is the best solution.What is the your opinion for this.Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing the advantages and disadvantages, I recommend mySQL **only if you really need a relational database**. I work with mongoDB and it's great advantage is rapid access and data entry, easy adaptation to project requirements change and virtually all transactions made ​​in sql are possible in NoSQL.

For you have an idea, the project in which work need not be relational and mySQL takes minutes to process while with mongoDB were seconds.

But only you know the project and the real needs analysis before architect it.

Comment: Thanks.Is it problem ,if I request data from the DB sequence.I mean this.Eg:  `function test(){ var a = db.getA() ; var b = db.getB(a) ......} `  is this not make traffic application between database

Comment: If access is a singleton no problem.

Comment: ok.What about Transaction Management.We can't do commit,rollback operation when data transaction with mongodb

Comment: this can help you http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/